# "Cherrypicking" data and loading "levels" of data without 2 separated procedures

Tags: c#, .net

Is there an (easy) way to establish an "arranged" level system (level 1 > level 2 > level 3) and a "cherrypick"- system (Get only Cat + Cat Owner + Cat Race)   without writing 2 separated procedures? Ideally where the level-system kind of uses the cherrypick-system but where I don't have to specify every "cherry" itself since I don't need to be able to cherrypick everything.

I'm thinking about something like this

```
GetCats(catId, 1); //Select cat with objects in level 1
GetCats(catId, 0, flag.Owner); //select Cat and load only Owner
```

The best way would to merge the following somehow together so the flag-system is'nt seperated from the level-system

```
public string GetCat(int catId, int level, flag cherries)
{
    //get Cat here
    if(level > 0)
    {
        Cat.Owner = ownerRepository.GetById(Cat.OwnerId);
        //load more
    }   
    if(level > 1)
    {
        //and so on
    }

    if(cherries.HasFlag(Owner) && Cat.Owner != null)
    {
        Cat.Owner = ownerRepository.GetById(Cat.OwnerId);
    }
    if(cherries.HasFlag(Race) && Cat.Race != null)
    {
        Cat.Race= RaceRepository.GetById(Cat.RaceId);
    }
    //more cherrypicking here
}
```

### Longer explanation:

I got an object , lets call it "Cat", with a lot of other properties like "Owner" . The information are loaded from a database(Cat and Owner are 2 tables) and the relations work via an Id. I load the data with the help of an repository which also fills the other objects so I can access Cat.Owner.Name for example. 
The loading works with different levels, level 0 only gets the cat itself, level 1 get the Cat and attaches the Owner-obj to Cat.Owner and the Race-obj to Cat.Race.

There are a lot of objects like Cat.Owner which get loaded when the the level hits a certain point.

I now need to access an object which only loads at a high level, but I don't need 90% of the other objects which are also loaded. I can write a new function where I only get the objects I need. This works fine but doesn't seem best practice for me, since I have to write another function if I have a similar problem in the future, which is very likely.

My idea was to use flags(enums) instead where I can specify which level I want to load. But then everybody had to commit every flag if they want the load the highest level. (every flag between the lowest and the highest flag)

Comment: Is it possible for you to implement read-on-request objects here? So get a `cat` and it just gets a `cat` but the first time you access the `owner` property it gets the `owner` from the database. That way you only get the data you need when you need it.

Comment: While I don't know of any such solution existing, you could possibly define the levels by creating a custom attribute which has a level property and putting that in your models, then in your getters, wrap it in something which will eager load the properties based on this custom attribute?

Comment: Going slightly off-topic here, but I use Dapper in these situations. In some cases I have a pretty hefty object graph that gets populated from a 5 table JOIN and it gets loaded damn fast (mainly because of a single call to database).

Comment: @Dave I think you mean lazy loading? The idea is quite nice and I'm pretty sure it would work. Unfortunately the project is quite big (a few hundred tables with thousands of fields) and implementing lazy loading would be a lot of work. But you could kinda kill the level-system then afaik, so still nifty. And I've never heard about Dapper yet, but seems quite interesting. I'm currently using the entity-framework.

Comment: @CtrlGate, lol yes - Lazy Loading (I can never remember that term!). Dapper is well worth a look (they use it here on SO I believe). It's very light weight so you could probably use it alongside EF.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly: You have a big (deep and wide) object graph and you want to be able to specify which level and which item to load in that graph. Sorry to put it this way, but I think this is a fool's errand. To demonstrate my point, Let's say you have 1000 nodes involving 30 tables. Do you really want to "set, say 100, bits" to know what to load? Or come up with your own language (like regex) to know what to load.

Comment: I would recommend Lazy Loading. The key would be to load not only that node and all nodes related to that table, but also some other tables (heuristically determined). This way, you will be able to optimize the number of DB calls while also not having to roll your own graph specification language

Answer (score 0):

You can use default values for the input parameters of the method and when calling the method, only pass the parameters that you want. If you don't pass a parameter, the default value will be used.

So your method will look like this:

```
public string GetCat(int catId, int level = 1, flag cherries = null)
{
    //get Cat here
    if(level > 0)
    {
        Cat.Owner = ownerRepository.GetById(Cat.OwnerId);
        //load more
    }   
    if(level > 1)
    {
        //and so on
    }

    if(cherries.HasFlag(Owner) && Cat.Owner != null)
    {
        Cat.Owner = ownerRepository.GetById(Cat.OwnerId);
    }
    if(cherries.HasFlag(Race) && Cat.Race != null)
    {
        Cat.Race= RaceRepository.GetById(Cat.RaceId);
    }
    //more cherrypicking here
}
```

Using the above method declaration,  the first parameter (catId) is mandatory and has to be passed when you call the method. The other two parameter are optional and if not defined in the method callm their defualt value will be used.

Comment: Yeah, then I won't have to pass another parameter but the logic (level-system and cherrypick-system) would be still separated. I would like to load Cat.Owner only once, but thanks for the answer!